Motivation behind axiom 4 in Gödel's ontological proof.
Axiom $4$ states:
$$\textbf{Ax. 4.}\quad P(\varphi) \implies \square P(\varphi)$$
I don't understand the logic behind this axiom. In general, I don't understand the distinction between $p$ and $\square p$. If you're asserting $p$, you're already stating its truth, it's already "necessarily true".
I'm sure I'm missing something, so I would be glad if you could enlighten me. Thanks in advance.

It’s been a while since I looked at his argument, but I think he’s using $P$ as “is a perfection” or “it is perfect that”. It’s a metaphysical claim that if something is perfect, then it is necessary. Apparently Gödel never saw a sunset, or an eclipse, or maybe I just have standards too low for his sense of ‘perfection’.

This is not a theology site.

In general, $\Box A$ means that $A$ holds at any accessible state. The other axioms of modal logic besides K and the duality of $\Diamond$ and $\Box$ modify the accessibility relation e.g., by making it transitive or reflexive or something. A helpful way of understanding the way the def. of $\Box$ operates at a semantic level using syntax is to employ special modal subproofs in a ND system for modal logic. Such a system for normal modal logics is is mentioned here under “Natural Deduction for Non-Classical Logics”: https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/.

@Shaun I don’t see why any theologian would seriously care about Gödel’s proof. Maybe William Craig would, but I don’t see how that would make this not a math question, especially since the content of it is asking about $\Box$, which has a clear mathematical meaning. Gödel’s argument is more of a mathematical reconstruction of an older argument anyway.

I think there are several moderators misunderstand this question. Modal logic is not a usual subject found in math and more likely in philosophy. But this is still math, not theology!

You should have mentioned the intended interpretation of the $P$ predicate in the question.

The point of $\square$, in general, is to reason about 'global' truth, whereas the normal notion of truth is 'local.' What exactly 'global' vs. 'local' means depends on your application, but it has (relatively) consistent structure regardless.
So, for instance, if you're using modal logic to reason about time, and $R$ means, "it's raining," then asserting $R$ means that it's raining right now (or at some designated moment in time), while $\square R$ means that it is always raining (always has been, always will be, is now). This is why you can't generally infer from $P$ to $\square P$. Just because something is true at a moment in time, or in a specific place, or ... doesn't mean it is true always, everywhere, etc.
The other modality $\lozenge$ is the "some" analogue to the "all" of $\square$. So $\lozenge R$ means, "there is some time at which it's raining." So, you can deduce $R ⇒ \lozenge R$, because if it's currently raining, right now is a time at which "it's raining" holds. But also if it rained last week, but isn't raining right now, $R$ is false, but $\lozenge R$ is still true.
So, according to wikipedia, $P$ in Gödel's argument is meant to classify "positive" properties (as in, "good," I guess). And the 'local' vs. 'global' distinction is meant to refer to, "possible worlds." The local case is the actual reality we live in, but there are other, different worlds we can imagine (or something like that). So, the axiom:
$$P(φ) ⇒ \square P(φ)$$
is supposedly saying something like, "what is good in our reality is good in every conceivable reality."

I’m not sure that characterization of $\Box$ is correct for temporal logic, since it requires $\Box \phi \to \phi$. Clearly the notion to which you refer means something, as I’ve seen it usually as $A(\phi):=(H(\phi) \land G(\phi) \land \phi)$ where $H$ is a $\Box$ operator that ranges over worlds that access the current world, and conversely for $G$.

This is a question about the basics of modal logic, not about the technical design of a specific temporal logic. Taking naive 'points in time' to be 'worlds' is just a mundane example.
